# Entity manager is undefined in custom validation nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

i am trying to create custom validation for unique values in all tables but it give me this error

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRepository')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRepository')
```

i think the EntityManger does't get injected
this is my validation constraint

```
export class IsUniqueConstraint  implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {

constructor( private readonly entityManager: EntityManager) {
}

async validate(
    value: any,
    args?: ValidationArguments
    ): Promise<boolean> {
        const {tableName, column}: IsUniqeInterface = args.constraints[0]            
        const dataExist = await this.entityManager.getRepository(tableName)
            .createQueryBuilder(tableName)
            .where({[column]: value})
            .getExists()
        return !dataExist
}
}
```

and i add in app.module the constraint in providers

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      port: parseInt(<string>process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
      synchronize: true,
      entities: [User,Role],
      logging: true,
    }),
    RoleModule,
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService,IsUniqueConstraint, EmailService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and this is my main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
    }),
  );
  useContainer(app.select(AppModule), {fallbackOnErrors: true});
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

and for typeorm versions

```
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.1",
"typeorm": "^0.3.17"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace constructor in class `IsUniqueConstraint`

```
constructor(private readonly entityManager: EntityManager) {}
```

for this

```
constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {}
```

import

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
```

You can get more detailed information here - https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't add `@Injectable()` on top of your `IsUniqueConstraint` class.

Here is my complete code and it works.

The **IsUniqueConstraint** class - `is.unique.constraint.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';
import {
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
  ValidationArguments,
} from 'class-validator';
import { IsUniqeInterface } from './is.unique';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'IsUniqueConstraint', async: true })
@Injectable()
export class IsUniqueConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(private readonly entityManager: EntityManager) {}
  async validate(value: any, args?: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
    // catch options from decorator
    const { tableName, column }: IsUniqeInterface = args.constraints[0];

    // database query check data is exists
    const dataExist = await this.entityManager
      .getRepository(tableName)
      .createQueryBuilder(tableName)
      .where({ [column]: value })
      .getExists();

    return !dataExist;
  }

  defaultMessage(validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): string {
    // return custom field message
    const field: string = validationArguments.property;
    return `${field} is already exist`;
  }
}
```

**The decorator function - `isUnique`** - `is.unique.ts`

```
import { ValidationOptions, registerDecorator } from 'class-validator';
import { IsUniqueConstraint } from './is.unique.constraint';

// decorator options interface
export type IsUniqeInterface = {
  tableName: string;
  column: string;
};

// decorator function
export function isUnique(
  options: IsUniqeInterface,
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions,
) {
  return function (object: any, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'isUnique',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [options],
      validator: IsUniqueConstraint,
    });
  };
}
```

To inject dependencies into your custom validator, you need to wrap the `AppModule` with `useContainer`.

In your `main.ts`, add the following line.

```
  useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });
  await app.listen(3000);
```

Also, make sure to import `useContainer` from `class-validator`

```
import { useContainer } from 'class-validator';
```

Here you can read more about it - https://github.com/typestack/class-validator?tab=readme-ov-file#using-service-container